# Synchronously run a task in the same thread (no threadpool) with a timeout

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, async-await, c#-5.0, continuations

I want to use Task<> type, but not with TPL, but with .NET4.5/C#async instead.

Thing is, I have some requirements for my case:

- I want the task to be run synchronously (some people recommend `RunSynchronously()`, others `Wait()`, and others `ContinueWith(_, TaskContinuationOptions.ExecuteSynchronously)`, which one is the adequate here?).
- I want the task to run in the **same thread** (so, not use the threadpool at all).
- I want the task to stop after a certain **timeout** has passed, and throw an exception.

For the latter, I think I need `Task.Delay()` but I'm not sure how to combine it with the first two requirements.
Thanks

Comment: `Task` IS part of the Task Parallel Library (TPL) and it DOES utilize a `ThreadPool` behind the scene, which means it gets scheduled by a `TaskSchedule` and WILL eventually run on a different thread.

Comment: no, there are ways to make it not use the threadpool by using a proper scheduler AFAIU

Comment: The whole point of using a `Task` object is to perform an asynchronous operation, as the the documentation of the class itself indicates.

Comment: I know what is the whole point, I just want to do something a bit different

Comment: I don't understand why do you want to use `Task` here. Wouldn't a normal method that accepts a timeout parameter work for you?

Comment: how to make that method do the work but cancel it if the timeout passes? (all in the same thread)

Comment: Maybe if you could say why it has to behave that way, we could understand more the goal behind this...

Answer (score 2):

This answer is based on @svick's comment.

I'm going to make the assumption that you want all the "work" of the method to be done on the same thread as the caller, but that you don't mind if a thread pool thread is used for cancellation purposes (I'm assuming this since you mentioned `Task.Delay` which will use a `Timer` which will use a thread pool thread when the timer fires.

That said, there would be no need for `Task`, since when the method returns you would know for certain that the Task was completed.  Just a regular method with a timeout will do:

```
static void DoSomethingOrThrowAfterTimeout(int millisecondsTimeout)
{
    CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource(millisecondsTimeout);
    CancellationToken ct = cts.Token;
    // do some work
    ct.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
    // do more work
    ct.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
    // repeat until done.
}
```

Obviously, with this approach of using cooperative cancellation, the method won't timeout *exactly* at the timeout, as it will be dependent on how small you can split up the work in the method.

If you want to avoid the usage of another thread (for the `CancellationTokenSource`), then you could track the starting time and then check how much time has passed (to see if you've exceeded the timeout) at various points in the method (like how `ct.ThrowIfCancellationRequested()` is used above.

Comment: @knocte, In that case you can't use `Task.Delay` or my `CancellationTokenSource` method as above, but rather you'll have to compare the start time of the method to the current time, perhaps using `Environment.TickCount` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.tickcount.aspx